# Typographic approach to a layout for a View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, typography

Preface:
I have a background about Tex/Latex and HTML/CSS and their metric system

This question is about to try to maintain the same metric approach with an Android View, long story short i would love to do 2 things:

- use typographic units like the `em`
- have a layouts composed with block units, like a book where you have a big container in the center of the page for the biggest part, a small rectangle as footer and/or as header, and eventually some floating box that contains some quotes or images.

Probably i can start from a Relative Layout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

My problem is i don't get what are all the typographic units available on Android.

I also don't get if there is a "Z axis management" that can allow a container and its content to be rendered on top of another underlying container. Something like when 2 box of text are near to each other and i want some text to break the box limits and still be rendered on top of the other box.

Maybe there is also some flow control on the text?

Comment: in the meantime i found this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension